# Image fetching issue from photo library for the selected cell?

Tags: ios, iphone, image, tableview

I have a tableview, My table view all cell having buttons.In my scenario the user tab first cell, that action going to photo library and choose from some images, finally that images come to cell.
that part i have done.

My problem is image coming only one cell.but i want show the images for the user selected cell.

```
UIImage * image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

self.imageView.image = image;
//[self saveImage];

if (_newMedia) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                   self,
                                   @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                   nil);
}
```

Cell for row atindexmethod:

```
BizDetails *bizdetails = [self.bizDetailsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

contactNo.text=bizdetails.contactGlobal;
customerId.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", bizdetails.bizcustomerId];
businessType.text=bizdetails.contactTypename;
firstName.text=bizdetails.userName;
option1.text=bizdetails.globalOption1;
option2.text=bizdetails.globalOption2;

NSLog(@"getting array %@",option1.text);
NSLog(@"getting array %@",option2.text);

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(useCameraRoll:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CamIcon.png"];
```

if i do anything in didselectrow method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CamIcon.png"];
```

finds an image in the app bundle and loads it to something. Can't tell if it's the cell, but it makes little sense being here. Partly because it's an explicit reference rather than a cell reference and partly because it references a bundle image.

It could possibly be used as a default image before a specific image is chosen, but it should still be a cell reference.

That goes for all of the other text you're setting with the content of `bizdetails`. You should have a custom cell subclass making these outlets available. It isn't clear from the code you added exactly what you have but it doesn't look right.

Using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` saves the photo to the album. This might not be much use to you as you can't get the image back in the future. You really need a way to update your data model with the image (save it to disk) or an image URL (save it to the photo library using `writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:`).

So, you need to change how you populate cells and how you save images in order to get specific images on each cell.

Comment: actually image fetching is working fine my issue is if i click 2nd 3rd cell etc..The corresponding images changes in 1st cell view only. this is my problem. if i click second cell i want to change image in 2nd cell only but my image changes in 1st cell....why it's happening?

Comment: I said that how you reference the cell is wrong and how you save images may not be very useful to you. Your first problem to solve is how you set data onto the cells. Why is it `self.imageView`?